# What Is The Status Of The Narration That says "If Jesus (Alaihisalam) were Alive..."?

Tags: hadith, ilm-ar-rijal, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

[image]

**The excerpt says that this was supposedly authenticated hy Imam Ibn Qayyim in his work called Madarijus Salikin. Is this true?**

Comment: Your picture doesn't even clearly say Ibn Qayyim authenticated it although phrased deceptively. And Ibn Kathir seems to quote with no chain

Comment: I don't find any instances of this addition of Isa (AS) to be quoted with an isnad in any of the books I searched. The narration with just Musa (AS) is famous.

Comment: even i am not aware of any narration mentioned for Musa (AS) and Isa (AS) together in the wording but for Musa (AS) alone we can find it in musnad ahmad and it is graded hasan by Shaykh Hamztul Zain in his classification.